# python scripts stops once internet down and do not start again

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python3 script which is running fine once I am connected to internet but once my modem resets it stops working. I am working in dynamic IP environment and need to continuously insert data in my database on the server.

Need guidance that if my connection goes down then my script should wait till it comes up and again start inserting data into server.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question isn't very clear. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Well, you haven't provided ANY code to work off of so this advice will be fairly generic, but the standard way to deal with something like this is to wrap the connection code inside of a while loop.

```
keep_running = true
while keep_running:
    # here establish_connection() is something you will have written
    connection = establish_connection()
    insert_into_database(some_data, connection)
```

To deal with the possibility of the connection being unavailable you then wrap that bit in a `try`/`except`

```
try:
    establish_connection()
except ConnectionError: # or whatever error you have
    # Do nothing and just cycle, maybe sleep if you  don't want to burn up your CPU
    pass
```

Putting it all together you get

```
keep_running = true
while keep_running:
    # here establish_connection() is something you will have written
    try:
        connection = establish_connection()
        insert_into_database(some_data, connection)
    except ConnectionError:
        # Do nothing and just cycle, maybe sleep if you  don't want to burn up your CPU
        pass
```